# Expected Value and Random variables for Uniformly Random Permutation Sets

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, expected-value

> **Question**
>
> Let $n$ and $k$ be integers such that n is even, $n\ge2$ and $1\le k\le n$. You are having a party where $n$ students attended.
>
> a) $k$ of these $n$ students are politically correct and, thus, refuse to say Merry Christmas.
>   Instead, they say Happy Holidays.
>
> b) $n - k$ of these $n$ students do not care about political correctness and, thus, they say Merry Christmas.
>
> Consider a uniformly random permutation of these n students. The positions in this permutation are numbered as $1,2,…,n$.
>
> Define the random variable $X$,
>
> $X$ = the number of positions with $i$ with 1<=$i$<=$\frac{n}{2}$ such that both students at positions $i$ and $2i$ are politically correct.
>
> What is the expected value $E(X)$ of the random variable $X$? (Use indicator variables)
>
> Options:
>
> a) $n$ $.$ $\frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}$
>
> b) $n$ $.$ $\frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{n(n-1)}$
>
> c) $\frac{n}{2}$ $.$ $\frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}$
>
> d) $\frac{n}{2}$ $.$ $\frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{n(n-1)}$
>
> **answer is c).**

**Attempt:**

Indicator Variable:

$X$ $= 1$ if  $i$ with 1<=$i$<=$\frac{n}{2}$ such that both students at positions $i$ and $2i$ are politically correct.

$X=0$ for all other cases

We need $E(X)$ = $\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} k . p(k)$

We have $\frac{n}{2}$ positions? but I can’t seem to find $p(k)$

There’s so much information given in this question that Im confused on how to break it down beyond the basic initial expected value steps.

Comment: It appears that this question is posted twice: (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019475/expected-value-and-random-variables).  Please do not double post questions.  You can edit a question that you've already posted.